# How to define the set of all ordered pairs whose first element coincides with $a’$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then, define the Cartesian product $C=A\times B$, with arbitrary element $c=(a,b)\in A\times B$. Further, take some $a’\in A$.

My goal is **to define the set of all ordered pairs whose first element coincides with $a’$**: namely, the set $\{(a,b)\in A\times B:a=a’\}$. However, I have two problems.

1. First, I am not sure whether the set-builder expression $\{(a,b)\in A\times B:a=a’\}$ is the correct expression to denote the set of all ordered pairs whose first element coincides with $a’$.
2. Second, I need to start the definition with $\{c\in C:\dots\}$ rather than with $\{(a,b)\in A\times B:\dots\}$. I have thought of using the set-builder expression $\{c\in C:c_A=a’\}$, but I am not sure whether it is legit to use $c_A$ to denote the first element of the pair $c\in C$.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If $a'$ is fixed and pre-specified, then $\{(a,b)\in A\times B\mid a=a'\}$ makes perfect sense. So do $\{(a',b)\mid b\in B\}$, and $\{a'\}\times B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people would be happy with your expression $\{(a,b) \in A \times B\  \colon \ a=a'\}$ in most contexts.  When you want something more formal, perhaps in some contexts in axiomatic set theory, you could write something like

$$\{c \in C\  \colon \ \exists b \in B, (a', b) = c\}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Suppose instead that $C=A\times B\times D$, with arbitrary element $c=(a,b,d)\in A\times B\times D$; and I wanted the set $\{(a,b,d)\in A\times B\times D:a=a’\}$. Would your expression be
\begin{gather}
\{c\in C:\exists b\in B,\exists d\in D,(a’,b,d)=c\}
\end{gather}
or
\begin{gather}
\{c\in C:\exists (b,d)\in B\times D,(a’,b,d)=c\}
\end{gather}
instead?

Comment: I don't see why $\{c \in C\  \colon \ \exists b \in B, (a', b) = c\}$ is more formal than $\{(a,b) \in A \times B\  \colon \ a=a'\}$. It looks like a step backwards to me. And $\{(a'b):b\in B\}$ is even better.

Comment: @Héctor, the first of those.  The quantifiers $\forall x$ and $\exists x$ are typically defined for variables $x$, not for general expressions.

Comment: @TonyK: $\{c \in C\ \colon \ \exists b \in B, (a', b) = c\}$ is more formal because, when $\{x \in A \ \colon \ P(x)\}$ is defined formally, it's typically defined just for atomic symbols $x$ assignable to variables.  If you're doing axiomatic set theory, that might matter to you.  If you're not, it probably won't.